# Is "query()" "put()" "remove()" in io.objectbox.Box<T> thread safe?

Tags: objectbox

I'm using the ObjectBox lib which is really useful, thanks for that.
In my case, I use "query" "put" a lot, I'm wondering is it thread safe?
Should I add `lock/synchronized(ReentrantReadWriteLock)` for it?

Answer (score 1):

ObjectBox is thread-safe and [transactional](https://docs.objectbox.io/transactions) so in general you are safe. One thing to watch out for are [parameters to queries](https://docs.objectbox.io/queries#reusing-queries-and-parameters). Of course, if you set parameters on the `Query` object, you have to ensure that those are not overwritten if you use the same object across threads.